# Scrapy how to scrape complicated tag

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying on scraping this but still couldn't figure it out. I can only get it under 1 column in excel file. Any kind soul willing to help me? The html code and the desired result is as below:

HTML code:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Also post the code efforts that you have made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate CSS selectors

- Acronym: .views-label-acronym
- Project: .views-field-title .field-content
- Researcher: .views-label-xml-researcher .field-content

etc.

Comment: how about some random div without class or id?  <div><strong>Max ERC Funding</strong></div>
1 999 172 €
<br><br>
<div><strong>Duration</strong></div>
Start date: 2014-04-01, End date: 2019-03-31

Comment: try to find a parent element and then: e.g. `.parent div strong::text`

Comment: but it gets 'Max ERC Funding' and 'Duration' instead of 1999172 and 2014-04-01

Comment: try to get the text of the parent element in this case like `.parent::text`

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired result with XPath in a more elegant way:

```
project_acronym = response.xpath('//span[.="Project acronym"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').get()
project = response.xpath('//span[.="Project"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').get()
```

Comment: alright thanks for the input! will try it in future if necessary